# How do I add custom RocketChat UI packages to overlay existing RocketChat UI packages similar to a Wordpress child theme?

Tags: meteor-blaze, rocket.chat

Right now I am working with Rocket.Chat and I need to make my own custom pages and CSS.  I copied my rocketchat:ui package and renamed it to be childtheme:ui and changed the name of my package in my package.js file to match my package name.  However, when I edit a page it still loads the original Rocket.Chat UI.  I'm not exactly sure how I can do this, but I'd like to load my UI after the original UI is loaded.  A Rocket.Chat developer told me to add a reference in one of my files: `Package.use()`

I don't know exactly where I can declare this reference or if this is even the best way to load my custom UI, but if anyone has experience I'd appreciate it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's `Package.use()` and not `Package.onUse()` ?
If your custom package is a copy of `rocketchat:ui` package, you should already have it.

Do your have your package declared in `.meteor/packages` ?